# Calculate point on a line by percent value

Tags: geometry

I have two Points

P1 P2

I'm looking for a function which gives me points between by a pectental value

examples:

f(P1,P2,0) = P1

f(P1,P2,1) = P2

f(P1,P2,0.5) = middle between this points

EDIT

```
public class Point {

    public double x = 0;
    public double y = 0;

    public Point() {
    }

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public Point getPointOnLine(Point to, double percent) {
        return add(to.sub(this).multiply(percent));
    }

    public Point multiply(double val) {
        return new Point(x + val, y * val);
    }

    public Point add(Point p) {
        return new Point(x + p.x, y + p.y);
    }

    public Point sub(Point p) {
        return new Point(x - p.x, y - p.y);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + x + "|" + y + ")";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new Point(8.284538269042969, 50.178332805633545).getPointOnLine(new Point(8.286751556396496, 50.17717752456665), 1));
    }

}
```

prints

```
(9.286751556396496|50.17717752456665)
```

but i would expect the coord of my second point

8.286751556396496, 50.17717752456665

Comment: $t\mapsto (1-t)P_1+tP_2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple linear interpolation: $f(P_1, P_2, t) = P_1 + t \cdot (P_2-P_1)$, with $t \in [0,1]$. Or $f(P_1, P_2, t) = P_1 + \frac{t}{100} \cdot (P_2-P_1)$ if $t$ is a percentage $\in [0,100]$.

Comment: thank you! seems that i couldnt find the right keywords for google i tried "points on straight line percent"

Comment: hi could you point me to the error in my java code please? I think it's exactly what youve written

Comment: @wutzebaer The `multiply` method is wrong: You have written `x + val` instead of `x * val`.

Comment: just got it in the same second =) big thanks for your time